# What is leaking in this statement using replaceObjectAtIndex

Tags: iphone, nsarray

**Instruments tells me the following line from the code below is leaking:** I can't figure out how to fix this leak.

**[self.selectedElement.usrAdvancedBuyingPercents replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:percentage]];**

```
 - (IBAction) simpleMarginSliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {  

NSDecimalNumber *percentage = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:[sender value]];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"#.##"];

[self.selectedElement.usrAdvancedBuyingPercents replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedRow withObject:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:percentage]];

[numberFormatter release];


}
```

Comment: Does replaceObjectAtIndex release what was previously at that index?

Comment: The code you posted looks correct to me. Can you post more specific information? (ie, what does Instruments say you're leaking?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSString you are creating from the number is not being released somewhere.

The problem is not in the code that is shown - it's somewhere else that is taking a string from that array, retaining it, then not releasing it.  Leaks just shows you where memory that is leaked was initially allocated, and the only thing on that line that is allocating memory is `[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:percentage]`.

Either that, or the whole array is not being released correctly (but then whatever builds usrAdvancedBuyingPercents would also show that is leaking).